# About atoi function

Tags: c

`

```
#include <unistd.h>

int ft_atoi(char *str)
{
    int c;
    int sign;
    int result;

    c = 0;
    sign = 1;
    result = 0;
    while ((str[c] >= '\t' && str[c] <= '\r') || str[c] == ' ')
    {
        c++;
    }
    while (str[c] == '+' || str[c] == '-')
    {
        if (str[c] == '-')
            sign *= -1;
        c++;
    }
    while (str[c] >= '0' && str[c] <= '9')
    {
        result = (str[c] - '0') + (result * 10);
        c++;
    }
    return (result * sign);
}

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *s = " ---+--+1234ab567";
    printf("%d", ft_atoi(s));
}
```

`

This line: result = (str[c] - '0') + (result * 10);
Why do we subtract zero and multiply by 10? How its convert ascii to int with this operations?
Thanks...

Comment: It subtracts the character literal `'0'`, not the number zero. Read it carefully. Inspect the values of every subexpression in your debugger.

Comment: `'0'` and `0` are not the same value. `'0'` is `48` (in ASCII and basically every other text encoding), `0` is `0`. So if you want to convert the *character* `'0'` to the *value* zero, you subtract `'0'` from it. With that hint, I suspect you can work out what the code is doing, especially if you step through with a debugger and watch the values of the variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*****Some detail before answering your question*****

Internally everything is a number a char is not an exception.
In C char is a promoted type of integer meaning characters are integer in C. The    char which is promoted type of integer are mapped to responding **ASCII** Value.

**For example:**

**Capital Letter Range**

65 => 'A' to 90 => 'Z'

**Small Letter Range**

97 => 'a' to 122 => 'z'

**Number Range**

48 => '0' to 57 => '9'

***To answer your question***

The ASCII CHARACTER '0' **subtracted** from any ASCII CHARACTER that is a digit(0-9) results to an actual Integer.

**For Example**

```
'9'(57) - '0'(48) = 9 (int)
'8'(56) - '0'(48) = 8 (int)
```

**Remember char are promoted integer in C** Read the detail to understand this statement.

And Also the ASCII CHARACTER '0' **added** to any INTEGER in the range(0-9) results to an ASCII CHARACTER.

**For Example**

```
9 + '0'(48) = '9'(57) (char)
8 + '0'(48) = '8' (56)(char)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! I'm really understood thanks to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please see [ASCII table](https://www.asciitable.com/)

The ASCII code for '0' is 48 - not zero. Therefore, to convert to decimal you need to subtract 48